What were the disciples astonished and afraid of in Mark 10:32?
Mark 10:32 (NIV)

They were on their way up to Jerusalem, with Jesus leading the way, and the disciples were astonished, while those who followed were afraid. Again he took the Twelve aside and told them what was going to happen to him.

The bold statement doesn't fit because there is no reason for the disciples to be astonished or afraid with Jesus leading the way. It makes more sense if their reactions refer to Mark 10:29-31;

29 “Truly I tell you,” Jesus replied, “no one who has left home or brothers or sisters or mother or father or children or fields for me and the gospel 30 will fail to receive a hundred times as much in this present age: homes, brothers, sisters, mothers, children and fields—along with persecutions—and in the age to come eternal life. 31 But many who are first will be last, and the last first.”

How does this explain their reaction in Mark 10:32?


“And they were in the way going up to Jerusalem; and Jesus went before them: and they were amazed; and as they followed, they were afraid. And he took again the twelve, and began to tell them what things should happen unto him,” (Mrk 10:32, KJV)

Here, Mark summarises a scene and the disciples' reaction before describing the scene in full detail. This, in a sense, is his introduction to a new narrative. It's somewhat like a prologue.
He goes on to narrate the reason for the fear and amazement in the following verses:

“Saying, Behold, we go up to Jerusalem; and the Son of man shall be delivered unto the chief priests, and unto the scribes; and they shall condemn him to death, and shall deliver him to the Gentiles: And they shall mock him, and shall scourge him, and shall spit upon him, and shall kill him: and the third day he shall rise again.” (Mrk 10:33-34, KJV)

KJV version tried to portend that by adding the word 'saying' which is written in italics. The ESV and RV versions follow the same idea. The Young Literal Translation shows the same idea but instead uses a dash before the narrative.
The disciples were amazed at Jesus's knowledge of what plan (by the Chief Priests and the Scribes) was going on in Jerusalem concerning him. They were also amazed at the statement that Jesus would resurrect after death. The disciples were fearful knowing that Jesus was walking into death.
In fact, from this narrative onwards, Mark began to provide a detailed progression of Jesus's journey towards Jerusalem, leading to his death.
Mar.10:32 is the bridge between the earlier chapters and the rest of the chapters following it.
This begins the next chapters of Mark's gospel.

We can only react to events as they unfold; it's impossible to take proactive measures against what hasn't yet occurred. To suggest that the disciples were astonished and afraid by what Jesus hadn't yet said is overly dramatic.

@VincentWong, you did not get the point. Verse 32 summarizes what Mark intended to show. The events had happened long before he wrote them, and it summarizes them after which he lets us into the event itself. It's like saying "I was shocked today!". Someone asks "What happened?". Then I narrate the story. "I was shocked today" was a summary of what happened. Likewise, verse 32 summarises what he intended to say and what he intended us to read from his narration.
